# SQL to create a column from the value of another column

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
|  id  |         name            |
----------------------------------
|  1   | 236 SRTD - Something 1  |
----------------------------------
|  2   | 236 SRTD - Something 2  |
----------------------------------
|  3   | 236 SRTD - Something 3  |
----------------------------------
|  4   | 387 SRTD - Something 1  |
```

from that table I would like to construct another similar view but that looks like the following:

```
|  id  |  SRTD  |         name            |
-------------------------------------------
|  1   |  236   | 236 SRTD - Something 1  |
-------------------------------------------
|  2   |  236   | 236 SRTD - Something 2  |
-------------------------------------------
|  3   |  236   | 236 SRTD - Something 3  |
-------------------------------------------
|  4   |  387   | 387 SRTD - Something 1  |
```

How can I modify the name column, obtain the SRTD number, and then create another column that contains that value.

Comment: Create a new column in the table, or just in the query output?

Comment: @RedFilter just the query output.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it doesn't matter to me which is used, once I have an idea I can easily convert it to either mysql or sql server.

Comment: And why does this deserve a SharePoint tag? Even if you're doing something in a web part its really nothing to do with SharePoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT id, SRTD = SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', name)), name
  FROM dbo.table;
```